# is it right to set goals?

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy

Is it right to set goals for yourself? How do you know that hashem knows you can accomplish more than the goal you have now? How do you know that hashem knows you bit more than you can chew?

Comment: I believe you may be asking how to choose just how high to set your goals, but its not very clear from the question right now.

Comment: seems unclear and possibly opinion based.

Answer (score 2):

I have heard on several occasions that the [Piaseczna Rebbe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalonymus_Kalman_Shapira) used to meet individually with each of his students to ask where they saw themselves one year, [five years, etc.] hence and encourage them to plan accordingly.

I think this would at least be an endorsement for the practice of setting goals.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, because he knows all, the same as before.